# ActiveAdmin Rails 4 - Form does not save record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I would like to know why ActiveAdmin does not save a record via a form in rails 4?
When I edit a record's title and content, I get the message "successfully updated" but the record is not saved. Thanks in advance

**static_pages.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register StaticPage do
  menu false
  config.filters = false

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
      f.input :unique_identifier
      f.input :title
      f.input :content, :label => "Content"
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

**static_page.rb**

```
class StaticPage < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :unique_identifier
end
```

**migration**

```
class CreateStaticPages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :static_pages do |t|
      t.string :unique_identifier
      t.string :title
      t.text :content
      t.boolean :is_enabled

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.0.rc1'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Fameus
gem "twitter", git: 'https://github.com/sferik/twitter.git'


# GUI
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'josevalim/inherited_resources'
gem 'best_in_place'



# API
gem 'rabl'
gem 'oj'

# Delayed Job
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'

# mysql
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'magic_encoding'

#
gem 'unicorn'

#
gem 'mixpanel_client'

# PArser
gem 'httparty'

# Monitor Performance
gem 'newrelic_rpm'

# Devise Localization
gem 'devise-i18n'

# Rails
gem 'protected_attributes'

# Assets
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

# Cache
gem 'memcachier'
gem 'dalli'

# Gem pg
gem 'pg'

gem 'spring', group: :development

group :production do
  gem 'thin'
end

gem 'formtastic', github: 'justinfrench/formtastic'
gem 'ransack', github: 'activerecord-hackery/ransack', branch: 'rails-4.1'
gem 'polyamorous', github: 'activerecord-hackery/polyamorous'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: 'master'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think rather than put your attr_accessible in your model you should try putting this on the top of your active admin static_pages.rb right above your `menu false`

```
permit_params :unique_identifier, :title, :content
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

The issue has been solved by appending the following line to the model:

```
attr_accessible :unique_identifier, :content, :title, :is_enabled
```

According to Rails 4 documentation attr_accessible is only necessary in Rails 3. Therefore it looks more like a bug on activeadmin.